# Adding private key to Google audio to text API

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have submitted a request for google Audio to text.  I received the name back, but I am unsure how to add private key info from file downloaded to:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/your-operation-name"

and then am I able to run the command from web or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the environment variable to use the private key as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#using_a_service_account). Though the link talks about Vision API, the process is similar to use Cloud Speech-to-Text API. Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-java) is additional documentation for authentication. This can be run from the web.